# Does angular single file component support sass/scss?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I have been using only multi-file format for angular components.  I was trying out Angular Element where I had to use single-file component in order to build the element.

I notice that the scss syntax doesn't work.  So instead of doing:

```
styles: [
  `
    ::ng-deep {
      .dropdown-menu {
        top: initial;
        left: initial;
      }
    }
  `
]
```

I had to do this:

```
styles: [
  `
    ::ng-deep .dropdown-menu {
      top: initial;
      left: initial;
    }
  `
]
```

Is there a way to enable scss support in single-file components?

Comment: `I had to use single-file` can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Paresh, he is looking to write scss inside the component.ts file in the `styles: []` this would be a new feature request

Comment: So only regular css is supported inside the styles block, right?

Comment: @AkberIqbal my question, why there is a requirement of using single file only?

Comment: @PareshLomate, you can ask techguy2000 directly :)

Comment: @techguy2000 why there is a requirement of using single file only?

Comment: guys, have you tried building an Angular Element in latest V7 versions?  With styleUrls, I get this error: ERROR in : Error: Cannot handle async resource. angularCompilerOptions.enableResourceInlining requires all resources to be statically resolvable.

Comment: Oh. I can turn off the inlining by modifying tsconfig.lib.json: "enableResourceInlining": false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only CSS is supported inline :

see official docs:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#non-css-style-files

Comment: The doc reads: Style strings added to the @Component.styles array must be written in CSS because the CLI cannot apply a preprocessor to inline styles.